# node js separate apps on same url divided by specific path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect, server

We have a server. Which have one domain. And we placed apps separately by one domain by specific url paths. For example `front-end` of app takes main url `/`. If requests comes to `/` it is front end app. If we add `/api` it will be redirected to `back-end` app. Any requests to `/api/` goes to back end. And I have separate second `node` back-end app. Which takes at `/node` url. And when I want to take image from `/node` on `localhost` I can take it like `localhost:5000/uloads/photoname.jpg`. Because it placed at `public` folder of `node` app. But on server I tried like `mysite.com/node/uploads/photoname.jpg` it throws error. If I try `mysite.com/uploads/photoname.jpg` it redirected to main app which placed by `/` url. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please post at least one part of the routers that you use in both apps? Are the two apps listening on different ports? O it's one app routing the requests to different hanlders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Proxy

I am pretty sure you can fix your issue by putting a proxy Server in front of all of your other servers. This is typically done with [nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/).

Comment: I am now usin proxy. And apps separated with nginx proxy

Comment: So did I help you ?